# What is the term for a wishy washy person?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-requests

I used jisho.org and could not find the term. A person unable to make a decision. Thank you.

Comment: How about this? http://jisho.org/search/優柔不断

Comment: @Kenji, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context what term I would use. Here are a few examples from ALC

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=wishy-washy&ref=wl

Answer (score 0):

My go-to Japanese term for wishy-washy is [中途半端](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%AD%E9%80%94%E5%8D%8A%E7%AB%AF)

Comment: To me, that term means something more along the lines of "half-assed" than "wishy-washy."

Comment: Yeah, it definitely isn't a direct translation of wishy-washy and can mean quite a few different things. It just depends on context and how exactly you want to use it.